How to center a column in the appbar
how do I Center a column in the Appbar? I've searched online and even after adding a row with mainAxisAlignment and mainAxisSize, the Column is still not centered. TIA for all inputs. Additionally, the page is a second page, hence, there is a leading icon.

return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Container(
          color: Colors.deepPurple,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                    child: Text(widget.id),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      _caption,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );


Your Column is already Centered in AppBar can you add your expected result image?

Hi, added the current image, as can be seen, the column is not centered.

You code works as intended:
Look how your widget appears: it correctly centers the column inside the AppBar.

And here's a little example that centers a column within app bar, it's all about setting centerTitle: true,
appBar: AppBar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  centerTitle: true,
  title: Column(
    children: [
      Text('First Text'),
      Text('Second Text'),
      
    ],
  ),

How it looks:

If you are expecting a different output, just let me know.

Updates
Now, The leading widget is in the center calculations, we must ignore it from calculation, which can be done by setting a similar widget that allocate the same width as leading in actions of the appbar:
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Container(
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Centered Centered'),Text('Centered'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    centerTitle: true,
    leadingWidth: 60,
    leading: GestureDetector(
      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    ) ,
    actions: [
      SizedBox(width: 60,),
    ],
  ),

which appears like this, it's totally centered:

Hope it helps you.

apologies, i should have mentioned that there is a leading icon that's why the column is not centered.

So, What do you want now?

as per the image above, i want the text to be centered

@deandrehaijiel  while having a leading widget, that's what happens:
suppose the appBar width = 400 px which equals to screen width.
The leading widget is rendered first, say it takes about 60px in width.
Then the title have the remaining space to be centered in which is 400 - 60 = 340 px.
Your title will be centered in that space (340 px), not in the whole 400 px.
So, if you really want to center that title in the whole width remove the leading widget. specially if it's a back button.

@A-E I realised that this (the image above) only happens if the title is too long, if its shortened, then the column will be centered. however, i would still want the long text and the back button to exist

@deandrehaijiel ok, look at updates.

@A-E i changed the 60 to MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, so that it will adapt to all screens. thank you so much!

@deandrehaijiel , u r wlcm.
